# Array Sum from Array and Some array blank

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is Array

```
Product Details = [{Amount: '49.95'}, {Amount: ''}]
```

Here is Javascript used:

```
function() {
  var prods = {{Product Details}}; // Product Araay
  var Amount = 0;
  var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = prods.length; i < len; i++) {
    Amount += parseInt(prods[i].Amount);
  }
  return Amount;
}
```

============= Result ==============

NaN

Comment: you are trying to add a number to something that is not a number. Consequently your result will be NaN :)

Comment: Please show how you are using your code. Currently there are a number of syntax errors, which leads me to believe this is not actually the code you are running...

Answer (score 1):

- just default the value to `0` if its a `falsy` value.
- also use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` because you have `float` values :)

```js
var Details = [{Amount: '49.95'}, {Amount: ''}, {Amount: '15.25'}]

function sums () {
  var prods = Details; // Product Array
  var Amount = 0;
  var i, len;
  for (i = 0, len = prods.length; i < len; i++) {
    Amount += parseFloat(prods[i].Amount || 0);
  }
  return Amount;
}

console.log(sums())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NaN` as a result because you are calling `parseInt` on an empty string for the second element, which returns `NaN`. Adding anything else to NaN will still be NaN.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using decimal numbers, you might want to use `parseFloat()` to keep the total exact.

```
products = [{ Amount: '49.95' }, { Amount: '12.32' }];

function sum() {
  let amount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(products[i].Amount);
    amount += parseFloat(products[i].Amount);
  }
  return amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is unary + operator which can replace parseInt/parseFloat:

```js
+'' === 0
```

Just for information, don't recommend to use it as it is less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice your array's second element has `{Amount: ''}`.  `parseInt('')` results in `NaN`, and any more math operations on `NaN` with result in `NaN`.

To avoid this, you can change the code to `Amount += parseInt(prods[i].Amount) || 0;`  Else you can use the unary `+` operator.

The fastest way to convert a string to a number in JavaScript is to use the unary `+` operator, which works for floating point numbers as well.

`Amount += +prods[i].Amount;`